# Язык Си, поле, вывести

Tags: c

Как вывести на консоль вот так заданное поле??

```
int deployment_grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
```

};

**вот так оно должно отображаться в консоле**
[image: вот так оно должно выглядить в консоле]

Comment: а что такое "выписать"?

Comment: вывести на экран (в консоль)

Comment: Имеется ввиду с линиями или без? Зависит от наличия в шрифте линий. Жирную линию в консоли - обычно её там нет. Задачу можно как упростить до простого вывода цифр, так и усложнить загрузкой шрифтов.

Comment: Штатными средствами вывести в таком виде "как на картинке" - нельзя. Специальными средствами вероятно можно, но нужно указать тип ос хотя бы.

Comment: сами числа, в таком же порядке,  друг под другом, без линий, шрифтов.

Comment: через цикл For() и вывести printf(), но что записывать в For(), я не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На лицо имеем двумерный массив, обходим его двумя циклами - один по строкам, другой по столбцам, пробел между столбцами, перенос строки между строками

```
int a,b;
for (a = 0; a < GRID_SIZE; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < GRID_SIZE; b++) {
        printf("%d ", deployment_grid[a][b]);
    }
    printf("\n"); // или \r\n, смотря что за консоль
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_line(int size)
{
    printf("+");
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("-+");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    #define GRID_SIZE 10
    int deployment_grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
};

    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        print_line(GRID_SIZE);
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("|%d", deployment_grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
    print_line(GRID_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```